# Way to increase scrolling speed beyond maximum

Tags: trackpad, ventura, macos

I know there's a way to increase the tracking speed, through the terminal, but what I specifically need is to increase the scrolling speed beyond the max point.

I am using my Mac with a 32" 4k monitor and there's no way to quickly scroll through an article. Scrolling is exceptionally slow.

As you can see I am already at the max:

[image]

Comment: Hello, you might want to try to press CMD + Up arrow to scroll to the top of a webpage or press CMD + Down arrow to scroll at the bottom of the page almost instantly.  Good luck!

Comment: I am using Magic Trackpad, not a 3rd party mouse.

Comment: Oh ok. It wasn't precised on the post.